# Show that $f(z) = z^n$ is an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Show that $f(z) = z^n$ is an entire function where $n = 0,1,2...$

I can show that $z$, $z^2$ and $z^3$ are entire functions but what about $z^n$ how do you crack that one.

Comment: An entire function can be wrote down as a power series which radius of convergence is infinite. The inverse statement is also true.

Comment: How did you show that $z, z^2, z^3$ are entire function? What is the problem in generalizing that to $z^n$?

Comment: I used Cauchy Riemann equations. I'm having trouble to do the same for $z^n$

Comment: Don't overuse the CR equations. They're a tool to use for functions where the definition of differentiability is hard to apply directly. The proof for entirety of $z^n$ works exactly the same as for differentiability of $x^n$ in the real case. Seriously, just copy it word for word and replace every instance of $\mathbb R$ by $\mathbb C$, and you got a valid proof.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: the product of two entire function is entire (product rule).

Now use induction for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** For $z \neq z_0$ and $n \ge 2$, we have

$$\frac{z^n - z_0^n}{z - z_0} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1}z^{n-1-k}z_0^k.$$